# Django extending model.User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to extend model.User in Django (using SQLite3). Here's my Model for UserProfiles:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True, related_name = 'user')
    bio = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, null = True, blank = True)
```

But when I run the server, I don't see UserProfiles as a separate tab. There exists a User tab but I don't see any of my custom fields in there. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior of Django? And how can I test this much code (manually is fine but how?) just to see if the behaviour is as expected.

Thank you very much!

Comment: by tabs ? do you mean admin tabs?

Comment: I mean hyperlinks! There's a hyperlink to User and Group by default but can't see one to UserProfiles!

Comment: Hyperlinks where exactly?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ - There is a heading called 'Authentication and Authorization' under which there are two hyperlinks/tabs - Users is one and Groups is another. If I try to add a user, I need to provide a username and password. There are other optional responses (first name, last name etc from model.User) but none of the ones I add show up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, you need to add `UserProfile` model to your admin panel.

Inside app folder where `UserProfile` is located, you will find a file named `admin.py`

Add the following:

```
from .models import UserProfile

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```